# Trying to install pygame on ubuntu which gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pygame

I am trying to install pygame using pip but whenever I do I get the error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hZGMxh/pygame/`. On the sites I have visited googling the errors it says to update setuptools. I do that but it tells me I already have the latest version. Below is the error I receive when I try to install it. I need it to use `HyperGAN` so I can't install `python3-pygame` as that is not installed as pygame so I get a no module named "pygame" installed. Many thanks.

```
dan@dan-VirtualBox:/home$ python -m pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/00/c8c0432a84fce4061fc9799747ea205805e247c559db1b71ac9f768e38e0/pygame-1.9.4.post1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using UNIX configuration...

Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
sh: 1: freetype-config: not found

Hunting dependencies...
WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
SDL     : found 1.2.15
FONT    : found
IMAGE   : found
MIXER   : found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
SCRAP   : found
PORTMIDI: found
PORTTIME: found
FREETYPE: not found
Missing dependencies

----------------------------------------
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-hZGMxh/pygame/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest pygame doesn't have all the binary packages (aka wheels). Try installing an older one.

```
% pip install pygame==1.9.4
```

Or follow the missing dependencies and install them.

```
% sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev
```

Good luck!

Comment: This was the package I was missing. Thanks! I also needed `libjpeg-dev libportmidi-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev libx11-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev`