# Error while trying to do download pygame on python3.8 arch linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, pygame, python-3.8

So while i try to download pygame using pip3 i get an error. I try Multiple ways

- sudo apt install python3-pygame
- sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
- sudo pip3 install pygame

  I try doing all of these but on the pip installation
  it gives me this error.

---

---

```sh
jorge@raspberrypi:~$ python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.2 MB 1.7 MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t3uuppky/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t3uuppky/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-t3uuppky/pygame/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-t3uuppky/pygame/
    Complete output (29 lines):
    
    
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...
    
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    
    Hunting dependencies...
    WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
    WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
    WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
    Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to install pygame on ubuntu which gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031260/trying-to-install-pygame-on-ubuntu-which-gives-error)

Comment: I assume that person was using python but i am using python3

Answer (score 0):

On archlinux, you can do a simple

```sh
$ sudo pacman -S python-pygame
```

and it will install [`pygame`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/python-pygame/) and all of its dependencies. What I see from your error is than the dependency [`freetype2`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/freetype2/) is not present on your machine. The above command will probably install it as a dependency probably, but it does not matter since it is all managed by `pacman`.

Comment: SInce i try install pacman it actually install the game pacman

Comment: No, no. pacman is archlinux's PACkage MANager. It has nothing to do with the game itself :). The command in the post when run will install `pygame` and not PacMan the game.

Comment: I know that. I just don't have the package manager installed

Comment: could you tell me how to install it i am sort of a noob in ubuntu arch

Comment: Ok so I think you are confusing the distro you're running. If that's the case, there's a good [read](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-linux-distros). Since you reported no issues running the `apt` command, I am assuming you are running Ubuntu. If that's the case, then this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031260/trying-to-install-pygame-on-ubuntu-which-gives-error) should answer it, as suggested by @SimonN in the comments. That is to say, all you need to run is `sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev` and then the pip command.